# How do I showcase a query that showcases the user stories under a given feature on my ADO Dashboard

Tags: azure-devops

I keep getting the erorr that it is a hiearchal query and it isn't possible to create it as a widget on the ADO Dashboard.

I tried manually adding each one but I realized for some other features there's around 70 user stories which in the long run isn't efficient at all.

I want to create a query that I am able to showcase the user stories under a given feature and be able to put it on my dashboard without having issues. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please let me know if my suggestion below is helpful for you? If it's helpful, to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept my answer below according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). If you have other question about this ticket, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get user stories under a given feature and display the results on the dashboard, you can refer to the following method.

1. Create a **shared query** as shown below. Parent is the work item id of your feature.
   [image]
2. Add a widget named [Query results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#azure-boards-widgets) to your dashboard. Select the query created from the first step at the Query box.

[image]

Then you can see related user stories in the widget.
[image]